# How get node features in DGL, using ID?

Tags: graph, deep-learning, pytorch, dgl, gnn

I'd like  to get nodes with their features  by using their IDS?
is it possible ? if yes ? how i can do that?
for example, I have source nodes IDs of an edge, as follows:

```
>> u, v = g.edges()
>> print(u)
tensor([0, 1, 0, 0, 1])
```

And thank you in advance .

Comment: You can do the following the to get features of the src from the edges. 
 ` 
   import dgl
    import torch
    g = dgl.graph(([1, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 0, 4, 2]))
    g.ndata['h'] = torch.tensor([[0.], [1.], [2.], [3.], [4.]])
    g.apply_edges(lambda edges: {'m': edges.src['h']})
    print(g.edata['m']) 
    '